# How do I list a live streamed event on my CV?

Tags: resume

For artists, it's traditional to list the location of an exhibition or a performance on your CV/resume, but I am having a bit of trouble listing the performances which the audience was distributed globally. I've seen "Instagram, Internet" used for the location on the CV of a performance artist, but I'm not sure if this is a format that should be used widely.

Comment: Are you talking about the location where the exhibition takes place, or the location people access/view it? I was confused as I think you are mixing terms here (location of an exhibition... audience was distributed globally)

Comment: I guess I'm confused as to which I'm supposed to list on my CV. What I've seen in the past is that the artist listed the location people access the exhibition.

Comment: In my case, I have a series of live streamed performances which could only be viewed through different social media applications, but I am unsure of if I should be listing the location they took place at or the location they were viewed at. (Apologies for any miscommunication.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's analyze what you are saying here. What I see is that there are two "locations":

1. The place **where the stream is coming from**. That is, the location where the filming or similar takes place.
2. The place from **where people are viewing it**. That is, where they stand or are located to see the exhibition.

In other words, I may be streaming video now from my house, so that location would be my country and area of residence.

However, people may see my stream from *anywhere* in the world, and that is a whole different location(s).

**So**, based on this, what I think would make sense when including this on a resume would be something like this:

> [Exhibition Name] - Streamed world-wide from [location where stream comes]

Optionally, you could include the estimated number of viewers for futher impact, something like:

> [Exhibition Name] - Streamed world-wide, for an audience of 1000 viewers, from [location where stream comes]